# voy a realizar una consulta con una condición y me sale estp: Unknown column 'SP' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, mysql

Esta son las lineas de consulta

```
$datos3= $conexion->query("select * from registro where placa =".$_GET['placa'])or die($conexion->error) ;
```

Comment: Estás seguro que esa placa no debe ir entre comillas simples (porque tal vez es un varchar)? tendrías que hacer algo como `where placa = 'dato_de_placa'`. Y lo otro, no pongas el contenido del GET directo en tu query, es una mala práctica y es vulnerable a SQL injection :) Busca sobre cómo usar PDO :)

Comment: le falta PDO  y bindValue a tu script XD

Comment: ¿Estás usando `PDO` o `mysqli`?

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que lo que compartió en la publicación es la consulta que generó el error?, porque observo que el error obedece a la referencia que se hace a una columna que no existe (columna `SP`). Otra cosa como recomendación, utiliza consultas preparadas para proteger tu consulta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu código faltan aspectos fundamentales de un programa medianamente escrito con rigor, lo cual implica:

- Prever **todos** los posibles errores y afrontarlos

  Esto implica verificar que hay conexión, que no hay datos esenciales vacíos, etc.
- Garantizar la seguridad e integridad de los datos

  Esto implica usar consultas preparadas en este contexto. En otros contextos implicaría saneamiento de datos u otras técnicas de seguridad.

Aplicando lo dicho, tu código podría escribirse así:

```
$outPut=array();
if ($conexion) {
    $mParam=!empty($_GET['placa']) ? $_GET['placa'] : NULL;
    if ($mParam) {
        #Reemplaza colA, colB por las columnas que necesitas
        $sql="select colA, colB from registro where placa=?";
        if ( $stmt= $conexion->prepare($sql) ) {
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $mParam);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($colA, $colB);
            while ( $stmt->fetch() ) {
                array_push($outPut, ['colA' => $colA, 'colB' => $colB]);
            }
        } else {
            $outPut['error']='Error preparando: '.$conexion->error;
        }
    } else {
        $outPut['error']='Datos del GET vacíos';
    }
} else {
    $outPut['error']='No hay conexión';
}
#Probamos el resultado final
var_dump($outPut);
```

De este modo debería funcionar y si no obtienes lo esperado, podrás saber rápidamente a qué se ha debido el fallo. Esto no es útil solamente a nivel de depuración, sino a nivel de decisión en un código en producción. Es decir, deberías establecer una política de manejo de errores, determinando qué acciones ejecutar o qué mensajes mostrar cuando el código falle por tal o cual motivo. Si no te adelantas a los errores, el usuario final tendrá una pantalla en blanco cuando estos ocurran... si hay algún botón o algo le dará decenas o centenas de veces para hacer marchar un código mudo que está fallando por algún motivo, sólo que en la forma de programar no se está avisando de esos fallos... las consecuencias de esto son impredecibles.

Si no has entendido algo de lo implementado pregunta en comentarios debajo de esta respuesta.

### PD

He asumido que estás trabajando con `mysqli`, por el uso que haces de `$conexion->error` en el código de la pregunta. Si usas PDO lo dices y adaptamos el código a esa API. Sea como sea, conviene siempre que indiques la API o herramienta que estás usando, así no hay que adivinar nada.